# firebase android facebookauthprovider cannot find symbol

Tags: facebook, authentication, flutter

I'm trying to add facebook login to the [flutter firebase_auth plugin](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/firebase_auth).

Here is an existing Google sign in method which runs fine:

```
private void handleSignInWithGoogle(MethodCall call, final Result result) {
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  Map<String, String> arguments = (Map<String, String>) call.arguments;
  String idToken = arguments.get("idToken");
  String accessToken = arguments.get("accessToken");
  AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, accessToken);
  firebaseAuth
        .signInWithCredential(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(activity, new SignInCompleteListener(result));
}
```

Here I added a Facebook sign in method which generates the error below:

```
private void handleSignInWithFacebook(MethodCall call, final Result result) {
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  Map<String, String> arguments = (Map<String, String>) call.arguments;
  String accessToken = arguments.get("accessToken");
  AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken);
  firebaseAuth
      .signInWithCredential(credential)
      .addOnCompleteListener(activity, new SignInCompleteListener(result));
}
```

Here is the full PR and a link to the build error on travis-ci: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/184

Here is the error generated locally:

```
/Users/frederickcook/GondolaProjects/Eng/plugins/packages/firebase_auth/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/firebaseauth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:120: error: cannot find symbol
AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(accessToken);
                            ^
symbol:   variable FacebookAuthProvider
location: class FirebaseAuthPlugin
```

Here is the error on travis-ci: https://travis-ci.org/flutter/plugins/builds/257319164

Note that both GoogleAuthProvider and FacebookAuthProvider are classes in the firebase auth package: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/package-summary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import com.google.firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider;` must additionally be added to file header to access the `FacebookAuthProvider` class.